# Creating a custom application in Umbraco 4.8+

Tags: c#, class, umbraco, backend

I've been trying to create a custom application tab in Umbraco 4.8+ but without avail.
Before Umbraco 4.8 you had to to adjust tables and what not, [but since 4.8 you should be able to add a class that will generate this for you automatically.](http://blog.mattbrailsford.com/2012/07/18/creating-custom-applications-and-trees-in-umbraco-4-8/)

So I've added a custom class in my Umbraco Web project in Visual Studio

```
[Application("myApp", "My App", "myapp.gif")]
public class MyApplicationName : IApplication
{
}
```

But the top line is giving me an error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Application'", I had to use `using umbraco.interfaces;` for `IApplication` but I can't seem to find any reference to `Application`?

I hope somebody can help me, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the umbraco.businesslogic

```
using umbraco.businesslogic;
using umbraco.interfaces;

[Application("myApp", "My App", "myapp.gif")]
public class Class1 : IApplication 
{
    public Class1()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
}
```